# continue to next iteration on TypeMismatch 2042 Error

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, continue, control-flow

I am looking for a Continue statement in VBA.

I found a VB.NET solution but the Excel "IDE" does not recognise it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx

I want to skip an iteration if an Error occurs. Is there any other way - a more elegant solution -  but GOTO (which imho is the worst case) or wrapping the whole Sub in an If-statement (which doesn't help readability either)?

Code snippet

```
'While Loop.... 

    For Each C In w.Range(w.Cells(1, 1), w.Cells(num_rw, num_col))
            If IsError(C.Value) Then:
                MsgBox ("File unsuitable!")
                'Continue While
            End If

            If Var1 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var1 Then: _
                  Set Var1_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
            If Var2 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var2 Then: _ 
                  Set Var2_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
            If Var3 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var3 Then:
                  Set Var3_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
        Next C
        If Var1_Range Is Nothing Then: 'Continue While


'WEND
```

Comment: So you want to go the next `C` if `C.Value` throws an error?

Comment: Sorry I missed a line of code when copying. This For loop is inside a big WHILE loop going through the worksheets (w) and I want to skip the worksheet if the value of C in this sheet is something like "Error 2042"

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for the While loop now. It will skip the rest of your code if `C.Value` throws an error, without using the `GoTo` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

If you want to skip the current iteration of the While loop if `C.Value` throws an error, just throw the rest of the code after the loop into an if statement and add a `fileError` variable:

```
Dim fileError As Boolean
'While Loop....

    fileError = False
    For Each C In w.Range(w.Cells(1, 1), w.Cells(num_rw, num_col))
        If IsError(C.Value) Then:
            MsgBox ("File unsuitable!")
            fileError = True
            Exit For
            'Continue While
        Else
            If Var1 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var1 Then: _
                  Set Var1_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
            If Var2 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var2 Then: _ 
                  Set Var2_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
            If Var3 <> "" Then
                If C.Value = Var3 Then:
                  Set Var3_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
            End If
        End If
    Next C
    If fileError = False Then
        If Var1_Range Is Nothing Then: 'Continue While
        .
        .  'Put the rest of the code in your While loop here
        .
        End If
    End If

'WEND
```

**OPTION 2**

Here is another option for accomplishing the same goal. I don't think its any cleaner than the other options, but it does avoid the extra If statement and the `GoTo` function:

```
'While Loop....
    Do
        For Each C In w.Range(w.Cells(1, 1), w.Cells(num_rw, num_col))
            If IsError(C.Value) Then:
                MsgBox ("File unsuitable!")
                Exit Do
                'Continue While
            Else
                If Var1 <> "" Then
                    If C.Value = Var1 Then: _
                      Set Var1_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
                End If
                If Var2 <> "" Then
                    If C.Value = Var2 Then: _ 
                      Set Var2_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
                End If
                If Var3 <> "" Then
                    If C.Value = Var3 Then:
                      Set Var3_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
                End If
            End If
        Next C
        If Var1_Range Is Nothing Then: 'Continue While
        .
        .
        .
        End If
        Exit Do 'Ensures the loop will never execute more than once
    Loop

'WEND
```

You could then put `Exit Do` wherever you want to skip to the next iteration of your While loop.

Comment: Well I agree on this as one way to achieve the desired behaviour. However... This still adds unwanted complexity but I assume there is no answer to my question "Is there any other way - a more elegant solution - but GOTO [...] or wrapping the whole Sub in an If-statement (which doesn't help readability either)? "

Comment: I've added another option for you. There is no Continue function in VBA, so I'm not sure your going to get a more elegant solution.

Comment: Was this second option more along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: Still not 100% but since I agree to that there is most likely no better way to do it. So I will mark it as accepted, to honour your work and time.

Comment: I appreciate that. If I come across a better solution I'll come back and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exit For to exit the most immediate/current For.

```
For Each C In w.Range(w.Cells(1, 1), w.Cells(num_rw, num_col))
    If IsError(C.Value) Then:
        MsgBox "File unsuitable!"
        Exit For
    End If

    If Var1 <> "" Then
        If C.Value = Var1 Then: _
          Set Var1_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
    End If
    If Var2 <> "" Then
        If C.Value = Var2 Then: _ 
          Set Var2_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
    End If
    If Var3 <> "" Then
        If C.Value = Var3 Then:
          Set Var3_Range = w.Range(w.Cells(C.Row, C.Column), w.Cells(num_rw, C.Column))
    End If
Next C
If Var1_Range Is Nothing Then: 'Continue While
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I didn't want to exit, yet skip. Matter of fact skip an iteration of the outside WHILE loop (sorry this wasn't quite clear in the snippet, i realized). That WHILE loop is doing more than just going through the FOR loop and I want to skip all of that if C in sheet w is errorprone and proceed with the next iteration of the WHILE loop.